# Selenium says element was clicked but it hasn't

Tags: php, selenium

I was clicking elements just fine before, and this all worked, however now when I try it after I've finished the script it doesn't want to do it,

on http://store.apple.com/hk/browse/home/shop_iphone/family/iphone/iphone4s I'm trying to click one of the iphones, by option-1 or option-2, I see there are several elements with that class, so I get all of them and select the first one, then send a click command.

CMD says that it has been executed however the element itself doesn't get clicked? I also tried it by CSS however same thing happens, the css seletor I've used was 'ul li.option-1'.

I'm using JSONWireProtocol with PHP and this used to work like a charm a few days back, but now it stopped, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you clicking buttons on a live site? ._. Selenium is for regression testing, not DoS attacks.

Comment: it's not DOS purposes, and how is this DOS anyway... All of this is for learning purposes only.

Comment: Decided to use X,Y click instead in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use X,Y click instead in the end. Needed to update selenium as it didn't want to work with firefox 9, but works like a charm now!